# Populating the value in listview in winform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am working on a desktop application that populate the list of all tables containing primary key in a combobox on selecting the corresponding database from another combo box like this

```
 ///This function binds the names of all the tables without primary keys in a dropdown cmbResults.

    public void GetNonPrimaryKeyTables()

        {

        //An instance of the connection string is created to manage the contents of the connection string.
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        //Declare the datasource,UserId,Password
        sqlConnection.DataSource = "192.168.10.3";
        sqlConnection.UserID = "gp";
        sqlConnection.Password = "gp";

        //Add the initial catalog to the connection string
        sqlConnection.InitialCatalog = Convert.ToString(cmbDatabases.SelectedValue);

        //Assign the ConnectionString value to a new variable 
        string connectionString = sqlConnection.ConnectionString;

        //Create the connection object
        SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        //To Open the connection.
        sConnection.Open();

        //Query to select table_names that doesn't have PRIMARY_KEY.
        string selectNonPrimaryKeys = @"SELECT 
                                              TABLE_NAME 
                                          FROM 
                                              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
                                         WHERE 
                                              CONSTRAINT_TYPE <> 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                      ORDER BY
                                              TABLE_NAME";

        //Create the command object
        SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(selectNonPrimaryKeys, sConnection);

        try
            {
            //Create the dataset
            DataSet dsListOfNonPrimaryKeys = new DataSet("INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS");

            //Create the dataadapter object
            SqlDataAdapter sDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectNonPrimaryKeys, sConnection);

            //Provides the master mapping between the sourcr table and system.data.datatable
            sDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS");

            //Fill the dataset
            sDataAdapter.Fill(dsListOfNonPrimaryKeys);

            //Bind the result combobox with non primary key table names
            DataViewManager dvmListOfNonPrimaryKeys = dsListOfNonPrimaryKeys.DefaultViewManager;
            cmbResults.DataSource = dsListOfNonPrimaryKeys.Tables["INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS"];
            cmbResults.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            cmbResults.ValueMember = ("");
            }
        catch(Exception ex)
            {
            //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
            EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
            log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            }
        finally
            {
            //If connection is not closed then close the connection
            if(sConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                sConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

But what I should do if I need to replace the combobox with a list view populating the same item when according to the selected database from another dropdown.

Can youguys please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `ListView`, try using a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), replacing these lines

```
cmbResults.DataSource = dsListOfNonPrimaryKeys.Tables["INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS"];
            cmbResults.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
            cmbResults.ValueMember = ("");
```

with this

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dsListOfNonPrimaryKeys.Tables["INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS"];
```

You can set properties on the `DataGridView` to have it look more like a `ListView`, for example:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
```

*Edit*

Also, looking at your query, if your goal is to get the tables that don't have primary keys, try this:

```
select t.TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS c 
        on t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA 
            and t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
            and c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
where t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    and c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE is null
```

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` view also includes rows for `FOREIGN KEY`, `CHECK`, and `UNIQUE` constraints, so your query as it stands now will select the table names associated with any of these constraints.